# Conflict when overwriting hadoop S3 configuration on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, minio

I have two MinIO storages as follow

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: "user"
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pwd"
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio:/data # For keeping actual data
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"

  minio2:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
      - "9003:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: "user2"
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pwd2"
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio2:/data # For keeping actual data
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
```

But when I try to read from the first MinIO and write to the second MinIO

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {

  // Initialization
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("O2SS_SparkServer")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.ui.port", "4040")
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

  // Read Csv from S3_1
  val endpoint  = "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
  val accessKey = "user"
  val secretKey = "pwd"
  val bucket    = "test_bucket"
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket.endpoint", endpoint)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket.access.key", accessKey)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket.secret.key", secretKey)
  val input     = spark.read.csv(s"s3a://$bucket/<someFile>.csv")

  // Write Csv to S3_2
  val endpoint2  = "http://127.0.0.1:9002"
  val accessKey2 = "user2"
  val secretKey2 = "pwd2"
  val bucket2    = "test_bucket"
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket2.endpoint", endpoint2)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket2.access.key", accessKey2)
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.s3a.bucket.$bucket2.secret.key", secretKey2)
  input.write.parquet(s"s3a://$bucket2/IfNotInS3_2_THENBUG.parquet")

}
```

It writes into the first MinIO instead of the second

*Remark*:

- I know about the "per Bucket" settings and how S3 bucket naming are unique. And so using S3 instead I will not encounter the problem => This is not the subject
- Currently on Spark 3.3.1

Comment: I think you should be using SparkSession config to set both bucket locations, rather than later on. Also, Minio can have multiple buckets in one server/cluster, so why do you need two separate/independent servers instead of clustering them, and then using one endpoint?

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks a lot for answering :) "Minio can have multiple buckets in one server/cluster" => You right. My example above was to simulate a read from MinIO than a write to S3 for example. The issue is being able to read & write with dynamic S3A credentials. On the example above "spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set" makes credential global to the SparkSession instead of an "on-read OR on-write" credential

Comment: I heard about behing able to specify directly the credentials inside the path: spark.read.csv("s3a://<accessKey>:<secretKey>@<endpoint>/<myBucketName>/<someFile>.csv"). But it's not usable anymore because of security issue (tested on Spark 3.3.1)

Comment: If you want to copy between buckets, instead of Spark, perhaps it would be better to use [S3DistCp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not just copying between buckets we are looking for :( In-between the "on-read OR on-write" in our actual prod, there are Spark computations